# CAKEPHP3 hasMany association with multiple values

Tags: mysql, has-many, cakephp-3.0

i have to 2 database tables:

**EMPLOYEES**

id | name

**ABSENCES**

id | date | employee_id

An employee hasMany absences. This is no problem. But there are also global absences with an employee_id = 0. So this absences belongs to every employee additionaly to his own custom absences.

I tried everything but it doesn't work.

This is the created SQL of the association:

```
SELECT * FROM absences Absences WHERE Absences.employee_id in (1))
```

If I add conditions to this association (or change finder method):

```
SELECT * FROM absences Absences WHERE (employee_id = 0) AND Absences.employee_id in (1))
```

Does anybody has a solution either to change the "AND" into an "OR" or add the employee_id into the "IN" clause?

Thank you,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query->find()->where(['employee_id IN ' => [0, $employeeId]]);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses

Comment: I think the OP is referring to conditions set in association defintion options, and the associations foreign key conditions that are automatically added by the ORM...